# Output fails to print all the data i've inputted

Tags: java, output

I've been working on the same piece of java code for over a week now, t used to be a complete mess however i have got it now (through about a million iterations) to a somewhat working stage. The output i need is all three student names at the end with either a pass or fail beside their name, however my code will only output the last students name that i put in, completely ignoring the rest of the data i input.

If someone could teach me where i have gone wrong and also the quality of code i've produced and iterated, it would be much appreciated. Also to those who downvote my posts simply because it may seem easy to you, we aren't all experienced as you and don't forget that you used to be in my position once, so be thoughtful.

```
class Main extends BIO {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        {
            int i = 0;
            int moduleMark = BIO.getInt();
            String first_name = BIO.getString();

            while (i++ < 3) {
                System.out.print("Enter The Students name  : ");
                first_name = BIO.getString();

                if (first_name.equals("END"))
                    break;

                System.out.print("Their Module mark   : ");
                moduleMark = BIO.getInt();


            }
            if (moduleMark >= 40) {
                System.out.println(first_name + " Pass");

            } else {
                System.out.println(first_name + " Fail");

            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would like to input a students name, then their mark, and repeat this three times, and then only at the end i want to print all three of their names, with either pass or fail beside each of their names, but only at the end.

Comment: I am a bit worried that you read a `int` and a `String` from `BIO` outside of the loop ... is it expected ? The first `firstname` and `moduleMark` are not used. It would be nice to have a [mcve] with some expected output

Comment: perhaps if you added comments, I am trying to learn the fundamentals of java, so it would probably benefit me more. I'm at university right now in a comp sci lecture.

Comment: also to narrow down what i need to do here it is "To pass a module you need to gain an average mark of

at least 40%
Write an application to read a series of data items
representing students performance in a module. The
data is terminated with a student name of END.
The output is the individual students result in the
module. Assume that the data is valid."

Comment: so for example the input would be,                                                                A N Other
50
B N Other
80
C N Other
35
END                                                                                                                                    & the output would be                                                                                    A N Other Pass
B N Other Pass
C N Other Fail

Comment: I added an answer. Do *not* just copy it, or you'll be screwing yourself over later. The concepts needed here are an absolute requirement to programming later. You cannot continue without understanding this stuff.

Comment: thank you, your help has been invaluable, thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`first_name` gets overwritten inside the loop constantly. When you exit the loop, `first_name` will be whatever the last name it received was.

If you can print them as you go, just print inside the loop. This will alternate between printing the results and asking for a new name/grade:

```
while (i++ < 3) {
    System.out.print("Enter The Students name  : ");
    first_name = BIO.getString();

    if (first_name.equals("END"))
        break;

    System.out.print("Their Module mark   : ");
    moduleMark = BIO.getInt();

    if (moduleMark >= 40) {
        System.out.println(first_name + " Pass");

    } else {
        System.out.println(first_name + " Fail");

}
```

If they *must* be printed at the end, you'll need to put the names and grades into lists, then iterate over the lists at the end:

```
// Create lists to hold grades and names
List<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
List<Integer> grades = new ArrayList<>();
while (i++ < 3) {
    System.out.print("Enter The Students name  : ");
    first_name = BIO.getString();

    if (first_name.equals("END"))
        break;

    // Add name to list
    names.add(first_name);

    System.out.print("Their Module mark   : ");
    moduleMark = BIO.getInt();

    // Add grade to list
    grades.add(moduleMark);

}

// Iterate both lists at once, printing inside the loop
for(int i = 0; i < names.size(); i++) {
    String name = names.get(i);
    Integer grade = grades.get(i);

    if (grade >= 40) {
        System.out.println(name + " Pass");

    } else {
        System.out.println(name + " Fail");

    }

}
```